# How to select second one in trending list of google webpage?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, xpath

```
package jdjjddk;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Htegsbn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\hp\\Downloads\\Compressed\\Chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Trending searches'][2]")).click();
        

    
    }

}
```

This is the code I wrote, while executing it **stops** at displaying the trending list but not clicking the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Selenium` you have FindElement**s**:

```
List<Element> elements = driver.findElements
(By.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Trending searches']"));
elements[2].click();
```